# What are canonical URLs and how do they affect your SEO?

Tags: seo, canonical-link

I've heard people mention the Canonical URL tag, but I don't know what it means or what its purpose is.

What is it and how does it affect SEO?

Answer (score 10):

Canonical URLs are used when you would otherwise have different URLs that point to the same content without actually redirecting. So let's say your domain is `example.com`; `www.example.com` and `example.com` are two different URLs, and if you don't redirect them to a standard (canonical) URL (for instance, `example.com`), search engines treat the two URLs as completely different pages. This causes the link popularity of the two URLs to be split, which is obviously very bad for SEO.

Comment: @musicfreak, if you can incorporate some of the info from those URLs into your answer it would be for the best.  External links die, decay and we are attempting to have a comprehensive knowledge base here.

Comment: One of the huge reasons for wanting to use Canonical URL's is if you have 2 different URLs pointing to the same content then their search value/weight can be split up between them.  Because it is split up between the two URLs it can lower the position your results are shown.