# Going to a page without "www" in my app causes the page to not load

Tags: asp.net, session-state

We've recently run into an issue with our ASP.NET application where if a user goes to `ourcompany.com` instead of `www.ourcompany.com`, they will sometimes end up on a page that does not load data from the database.  The issue seems to be related to our SSL certificate, but I've been tasked to investigate a way on the code side to fix this.

Here's the specific use case:

There is a user registration page that new users get sent to after they "quick register" (enter name, email, phone).  With "www" in the URL (e.g. "www.ourcompany.com") it works fine, they can proceed as normal.  However, if they browsed to just "ourcompany.com" or had that bookmarked, when they go to that page some data is not loaded (specifically a list of states from the DB) and, worse, if they try to submit the page they are kicked out entirely and sent back to the home page.

I will go in more detail if necessary but my question is simply if there is an application setting I can say to keep the session for the app regardless of if the URL has the "www" or not?  Buying a second SSL cert isn't an option at this point unless there is no recourse, and I have to look at a way to solve this without another SSL.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you perhaps value SEO on your site, would it be good to consider my answer of removing the canonical urls? See as to why its bad to have both showing the same content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047438/what-are-canonical-urls-and-how-does-it-effect-your-seo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update, I was able to fix the problem with a web.config entry:

```
<httpCookies domain=".mycompany.com" />
```

After adding that, the problem went away.

Answer (score 3):

When your users go to `www.ourcompany.com` they get a session cookie for the `www` subdomain.  By default, cookies are not shared across subdomains, which is why users going to `ourcompany.com` do not have access to their sessions.

There is a useful thread discussing this issue [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t108519-session-cookie-not-accessible-across-sub-domains.html).  The suggested solution is:

> By the way, I implemented a fairly good fix/hack today. Put this code
>   on every page: Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Value =
>   Session.SessionID; Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Domain =
>   ".mydomain.com";
>
> Those two lines of code rewrite the Session cookie so it's now
>   accessible across sub-domains.
>
> Doug, 23 Aug 2005

Comment: I'll check that out; thanks.  Would putting that code in Global.asax work, do you think?  There are a hundred or more files that may or may not have similar issues (we only know of one, however).

Comment: Worth trying!  How about in Application_BeginRequest, if you have access to the Response object at that point?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you are trying to solve the wrong problem?

Is it possible for you to just implement URL rewriting and make it consistent?

So for example, http://example.com redirects to http://www.example.com ?

For an example of managing rewriting see:

http://paulstack.co.uk/blog/post/iis-rewrite-tool-the-pain-of-a-simple-rule-change.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From the browsers point of view, `www.mysite.com` is a different site than `mysite.com`.

If you have a rewrite engine, add a rule to send all requests to www that don't already have it.

Or (this is what I did) **add a separate IIS site with the "mysite.com" host header and set  the IIS flag to redirect all traffic to www**.

In either of these cases, any time a browser requests a page without the www prefix, it will receive a redirect response sending it to the correct page.

Here's the redirect site home directory properties:

[image]

And the relevant host header setting:

[image]

This fixes the issue without requiring code changes, and incidentally prevents duplicate search results from Google etc.