# Google NEWS not acknowledging my canonical tag

Tags: reactjs, rss, seo, google-news

I have been struggling with a situation where google news bot is getting all the other info from my website correctly but is not able to pick up canonical tag. I have created my website in ReactJS.

Here is the link to my website page which I need google news to detect it's canonical.[my website link](https://www.explorebit.io/article/EB%2520Daily%2520-%252017%2520Aug%25202020)

Can anyone help what implementation is wrong with the canonical tag on my website or anything missing out on my part?

Comment: General SEO questions such as "Why is google doing X" are off-topic for stack overflow, see the [tag guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo).

Comment: That being said, from a sample it looks like all the news articles on your site are setting their canonical link to be the root page of your site: `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.explorebit.io/"/>`.  Is that what you want -- the canonical link for all your news articles is your site's root?  [Canonical links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) are an *HTML element that helps webmasters prevent duplicate content issues in search engine optimization* but your site's root and all your news articles are not in fact identical.

Comment: Yes this is where I am stuck why is it taking root page as canonical not actual page url

Comment: Because the HTML in your website explicitly specifies that it should?  When I view the source for the linked page, it starts out `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1"/><meta charSet="utf-8"/><title>Article - Explorebit</title><meta name="theme-color" content="#4A00E0"/><link rel="canonical" href="https://www.explorebit.io/"/>`

Comment: See maybe [How to use rel='canonical' properly](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/848/100199) and [What are canonical URLs and how do they affect your SEO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1047438/3744182).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.